# Sound/vibration from PRV

Tags: plumbing, water-pressure, valve

Back in September of 2020 I installed a whole house filter system (iSpring). The PRV did a little vibration/noise and I adjusted the pressure slightly and it stopped. Did some internet research and found that the PRV could possibly need to be cleaned. Took it apart and cleaned the screen. Put it back together and it would not stop leaking.

So I replaced it with a new one. The vibration/noise is now constant. Now matter what I do it won't go away. If I bypass the filter system the vibration/noise stops. I put new filters in the system and that did not correct the issue. Incoming water pressure is 120psi and I have the PRV set to 55psi. The PRV is just out of the picture to the right and water flow is from right to left. Suggestions?

[image: ispring Filter system]

Comment: Maybe it would work better if you reduce the pressure after your filter then you have the added pressure to help push the water across the filter media.  What psi is your filter system rated for?